# Can an Arduino emulate a USB mass storage device?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, sd-card

**Question:**

Can I connect an Arduino's USB port to the USB port of another embedded device that is expecting a USB thumb/flash device?

Or, can I connect a USB module to this embedded device, with the other end connected to GPIO's of the Arduino?

This embedded USB thumb device requires a thumb drive to transfer a file. I need to emulate the connection, disconnection, and thumb drive with the folder and file with a Arduino.

Is it possible to emulate an USB thumb drive between an Arduino and an embedded device's USB port?

**Research:**

I saw a couple other questions that talk about USB being a master/slave configuration and that certain IC are required. Additionally, that there were some cables that can be used for two-way data transfer (mostly for PC to PC data transfers). If that is the case, could one of those cables be used for this configuration? Which cable would work?

**Possible Solution:**

The embedded device I need to emulate a thumb drive on will automatically search for the file in a specific folder of the thumb drive. Would I be able to partition a section of an SD card with the SD card module to appear as a thumb drive, and then connect that partition to the embedded device via USB-A to USB-A cable?

**Diagram:**

Arduino USB Port -> USB Cable -> Embedded Device USB Port
Arduino GPIO -> USB Module -> USB Cable -> Embedded Device USB Port

Requirements:

Connection via USB cable between Arduino and an embedded device's USB port.
Ability to emulate the connection and disconnection of a USB thumb drive on the embedded device.

Comment: Not with an UNO. Could you expand on what it is you want to achieve? What is the end goal here?

Comment: Sure. I want to be able to emulate a USB thumb drive for an embedded system that has a USB port. You usually plug in the USB thumb drive into the embedded system, and then it reboots when it reads a file from the USB thumb drive. I'd like to develop something where I can emulate the plugging in/unplugging the USB thumb drive with that file in it's folder.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a regular flash-drive, but have the Arduino disconnect and reconnect it. Using something like a MUX (multiplexer), or maybe even a few relays. Just get a usb extension cable, and cut it in the middle. Then connect the 4 wires inside via the MUX/relays.

Comment: On a side-note. The newer raspberry pis can act as a Mass Storage Device.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi sounds promising. I want to develop a program to upload/download the binary file on the mass storage device. Maybe the Pi is a better option?

Comment: The MUX or relays might be a good idea to emulate the insertion/removal of the USB thumb drive.

Comment: Anything else you want to know?

Comment: This is indeed not a fit for an Uno, though one of the ARM or 32u4 based boards (Arduino, Teensy, or other) could work up to the on-board storage size or with an SPI flash.  In the raspberry pi world only the boards without a hub in the way (such as the zero or model A) can do it, but pi's add a lot of delicate software state.

Comment: What are the Arduino 32u4 boards? I read about the AVR boards a little bit, but I'm not sure how they differ from the popular Arduino boards. Do you have a suggestion for an ARM board for this particular configuration?

Comment: The Arduino functions as a USB client device, not a USB host.
You can get a shield which claims to allow the Arduino to operate as a USB Host to allow it to control various USB devices including thumb drives: [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947)

Comment: check out http://elasticsheep.com/2010/04/teensy2-usb-mass-storage-with-an-sd-card/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of this device from Sparkfun appears to match the OP's requirement for integrating an Arduino with other USB devices by enabling the Arduino to acts as a USB host. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947

Comment: This (Arduino is USB host so e.g. memory stick could be read by Arduino) is the opposite of what is being asked (Arduino acts as memory stick).